# How can I pass the value from angular to rest for map<string, string> field object on the rest?

Tags: java, json, angularjs, rest

I have the rest method which take a object parameter with Map field.

```
class myClass{
Map<String, String>;
get
set
}
```

And rest method. which take with object as parameter:

```
@POST
public Response test(MyClass myClass){
}
```

On the client I am doing ajax request with passing parameters as json. For example:`data: JSON.stringify({objectField:$scope.example})`. I have the string on the client such as:

property:value property1:value1...propertyn:valuen.

I want to pass it on the server side so on the server side I get Map with with properties in the object myClass.

Comment: why you needed map here.. you can simply get property from class object.

Comment: ok. now i have property as map on the server. How can I store the property in this case?

Comment: how your web.xml looks like, could you please share that?

Comment: I couldn't but there are nothing to help with it. It is about how to pass such string :property:value property1:value1...propertyn:valuen to rest method for map<string, string> field in the paramer object. I don't know possible it or not.

Comment: believe  you have the following entry in your web.xml

Comment: <init-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>

Comment: okay. thank you. maybe you have some tutorial or article about that?

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/json.html, look at this and carefully see the section 5.7 and 5.8, that might help you